# How to authenticate the ldap server while application load login page?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

Hi i have created my web application in java to authenticate my application i can check the credentials in active directory. If user typed his user name and password means it works fine.

My question is, if the user already logged in his personal computer which is present in the domain by using his username and password. If the user open my web application means i need to go inside the home page without typed the username and password in the login page. How can i do this? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do a google search on `Single sign-on`.

Comment: This is a job for JAAS with the NTLM LoginModule.

Answer (score 1):

Once the user is logged in successfully you can store some attributes in the session. You can then check on each page load whether the session is valid before allowing access. At a more comprehensive level this can be done using a Filter. Read a little bit on sessions here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19644-01/817-5451/dwsessn.html

Comment: The user logged in his personal computer only not my application. If user logged in my application means i can store the credentials in the session.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read credentials from a user's browser, as someone suggested search Single Sign-on (SSO). There are a number of ways SSO can be implemented by your application, Kerberos-SPNEGO might be most suited for your requirement. But you can make a call once you have better understanding of SSO concepts.